# Converting a single row into two

Tags: python, pandas

I have this daily stats churned out from a system which outputs total sales and units sold per region group. For my analysis, I want to breakdown the entries into regions instead of region group. I'm trying to look for a way to split each row into per region with the respective measures.

I have historical percentages on the market share per region which I'll use to come up with the estimated sales and units sold.

I can do this manually in excel but given how i'll be doing this on a weekly basis, I'm looking for a way to automate it via python.

My data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpcaK.jpg
Goal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym1Om.jpg

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: How are you calculating the new `sales` and `units sold`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, when you're doing DS researches try to find the most appropriate way in your personal case. There's nothing bad in using all Excel functionality to solve your issue, scripting, etc.

However, if you really-really want to use pandas, then what I would do in your case - just .append() and then split on regions and grouping by sales or made up a function with for..loop.